# How to use slices and maps with the k8s.io/code-generator

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-custom-resources

I'm writing a Kubernetes Controller listening on a *Environment* Custom Resource.

The *pkg/apis/environment/v1alpha1/types.go* has the following content:

```
package v1alpha1

import (
    meta_v1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

// +genclient
// +genclient:noStatus
// +k8s:deepcopy-gen:interfaces=k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime.Object

// Environment describes an Environment resource
type Environment struct {
    meta_v1.TypeMeta   `json:",inline"`
    meta_v1.ObjectMeta `json:"metadata,omitempty"`
    Spec               EnvironmentSpec `json:"spec"`
}

// EnvironmentSpec contains the specs for an Environment resource
type EnvironmentSpec struct {
    Services []Service `json:"services"`
}

// +k8s:deepcopy-gen:interfaces=k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime.Object

// EnvironmentList is a list of Environment resources
type EnvironmentList struct {
    meta_v1.TypeMeta `json:",inline"`
    meta_v1.ListMeta `json:"metadata"`

    Items []Environment `json:"items"`
}

// Service describes a Service in the Environment Custom Resource
type Service struct {
    Code       string `json:"code"`
    Parameters struct {
        Foo map[string]string `json:"foo"`
        Bar int               `json:"bar"`
    } `json:"parameters"`
}
```

After running the k8s.io/code-generator/generate-groups.sh script, I end up with a faulty *pkg/apis/environment/v1alpha1/zz_generated.deepcopy.go* file. The problem comes from this generated method:

```
// DeepCopyInto is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, writing into out. in must be non-nil.
func (in *Service) DeepCopyInto(out *Service) {
    *out = *in
    in.Parameters.DeepCopyInto(&out.Parameters)
    return
}
```

Trying to build or run this code will give me the following error

```
pkg/apis/environment/v1alpha1/zz_generated.deepcopy.go:113:15: in.Parameters.DeepCopyInto undefined (type struct { Foo map[string]string "json:\"foo\""; Bar int "json:\"bar\"" } has no field or method DeepCopyInto)
```

As soon as I have a *Map* or a *Slice* inside an anonymous struct included in the *Parameters* struct, I encounter this error.

**WORKAROUND**

A workaround to this is to create a named type that will contain the map. For example I refactored the *Service* struct like this:

```
// Service describes a Service in the Environment Custom Resource
type Service struct {
    Code       string `json:"code"`
    Parameters FooBar `json:"parameters"`
}

type FooBar struct {
    Foo map[string]string `json:"foo"`
    Bar int               `json:"bar"`
}
```

The generated `func (in *Service) DeepCopyInto(out *Service)` does not change, but the following 2 new methods are created:

```
// DeepCopyInto is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, writing into out. in must be non-nil.
func (in *FooBar) DeepCopyInto(out *FooBar) {
    *out = *in
    if in.Foo != nil {
        in, out := &in.Foo, &out.Foo
        *out = make(map[string]string, len(*in))
        for key, val := range *in {
            (*out)[key] = val
        }
    }
    return
}

// DeepCopy is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, creating a new FooBar.
func (in *FooBar) DeepCopy() *FooBar {
    if in == nil {
        return nil
    }
    out := new(FooBar)
    in.DeepCopyInto(out)
    return out
}
```

And now, I don't have any issues building and running the code.

This workaround is painful because my real *Service* struct is much bigger than in this example.

Is there a way to use maps and slices inside of anonymous func with the code-generator?

Comment: did you figure out how to do it? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I've opened an issue concerning this, but got no answers. Nobody from the Slack channel was able to help either. I'm just assuming this is not/won't be supported, so I converted all my anonymous structs into named ones.